# How to format code in Textmate

Tags: formatting, textmate

I like Textmate but its really driving me crazy when it comes to formatting code whatever the language I'm working with. Is there any way to format code? shortcut, bundle or anything that can help (eg ctrl+shift+F in netbeans)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

There is a **Reformat Paragraph** command under the **Text** menu but it is mostly useless for programming.

Some language-specific bundles (like **Javascript Tools**) offer reformatting options, though.

Comment: God help us please :)

Comment: God is working on it ↓

Answer (score 2):

Textmate 2 has indenting intelligence for each language (as much as it can: See below).

You can re-indent a block with `⌥⌘-[`
You can re-wrap lines with `^-Q`
You can align code on symbols with `^⌥⌘-9`

Example indentation rule in Settings (no need for casual users to edit these)

```
{   increaseIndentPattern = '(?x)
    (   \{ (?! .* \} ) .*
    |   array\(
    |   (\[)
    |   ((else)?if|else|for(each)?|while|switch) .* :
    )   \s* (/[/*] .*)? $';
decreaseIndentPattern = '(?x)
    ^ (.* \*/)? \s*
    (
        (\})         |
        (\)[;,])     |
        (\][;,])     |
        (else:)      |
        ((end(if|for(each)?|while|switch));)
    )
';
indentNextLinePattern = '(?x)^(?! .*? (<\?|\?>) )
    ( . ( (?![/*]) | /(/.*$|\*.*?\*/ \s*) ) )*
    [^\s;:{}(,] \s*
    ( /(/.*$|\*.*?\*/ \s*) )*
    $
';
unIndentedLinePattern = '^\s*$';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Today I found the "Tidy" option under Bundles > HTML and it worked great. (Ctrl-Shift-H). I can't speak to how well it works for other languages, though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's still available on TextMate version 2.0.23, however, it _mostly_ works; it leaves empty closing tags on the next line unindented instead of directly concatenating the opening tag (like, what should be `\t\t\t<the-tag></the-tag>` instead is `\t\t\t<the-tag>\n</the-tag>`. So... needs some work. Not sure how to improve that yet. Yes I know proper empty tag would just be `<the-tag/>`, but I'm not expecting TextMate to make that change just for indentation formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is re-indent:

1. select code
2. text > indent line

All it does is indent each nested level more than its parent. It wont erase empty lines or create any carriage returns.

Personally I love this because it seems to be language agnostic. Tested with HTML, ERB, CSS, SCSS.

Comment: There's no Indent Line Text for TextMate 2, but then, your answer's over 10 years old, so it's annoying that it's part of a top search result.